# How do I derive a reduction formula for $\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate a reduction formula for the indefinite integral of $\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}dx$ , for any positive integer n?

I have tried integration by parts, with $u=x^2$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ = $\frac{1}{a\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1}}$ but still unable to see any recurring pattern.

Can someone please guide me/show me a sample solution?

Comment: Where is the $n$?

Comment: ahh it was a typo, edited. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let put $x=a\sinh(t)$ with $a\neq0$.

using $$dx=a\cosh(t)dt$$  and

$$\sinh^2(t)+1=\cosh^2(t),$$ the integral becomes

$$\frac{a^5}{|a|}\int \sinh^4(t)dt$$

which can be computed after the linearisation of $\sinh^4(t)$
by Euler and binomial formulas.